# clip csv-file with ogr2ogr

Tags: ogr2ogr

I'm trying to clip a csv-file containing xyz-data (points) by an irregular shaped polygon in ogr2ogr. My code runs without any errors or warnings, but it returns an exact copy of the input-csv. What am I doing wrong?

My code is: 
`ogr2ogr -f CSV output.csv -clipsrc clip_polygon.shp -clipsrclayer clip_polygon input.vrt`

The vrt-file looks like:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="test_layer">
       <SrcDataSource>input.csv</SrcDataSource>
       <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
       <LayerSRS>EPSG:25831</LayerSRS>
       <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="field_1" y="field_2" z="field_3"/>
   </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Comment: Has the polygon shapefile the same CRS, and do the extents form ogrinfo and gdalinfo match?

Comment: Yes, both the .shp as the .vrt have the same EPSG-code. When I visualise the .csv and and .shp in ArcGIS, it is clear that they both have the same spatial extent.

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, but I put `dst_datasource_name src_datasource_name` always together behind the options. And I think to remember that csv, vrt and `<OGRVRTLAYER name >` should be the same.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. If I set the output data type to GeoJSON, it filters correctly by my `-clipsrc`. I can then convert that output back to CSV. Seems like bug.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, adding `-lco GEOMETRY=AS_WKT` to my `ogr2ogr` command worked.

Here's my VRT (it's polygon data, not point):

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
        <OGRVRTLayer name="data">
            <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">data.csv</SrcDataSource>
            <SrcLayer>data</SrcLayer>
            <GeometryType>wkbPolygon</GeometryType>
            <GeometryField encoding="WKT" field='field_1'/>
        </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

This ogr2ogr command didn't filter the input CSV at all:
`ogr2ogr -f CSV output.csv data.vrt -clipsrc -50.0 -10.0 -40.0 0.0`

But this one did:
`ogr2ogr -f CSV output.csv data.vrt -clipsrc -50.0 -10.0 -40.0 0.0 -lco GEOMETRY=AS_WKT`

No idea why a layer creation option (-lco) would have this affect, but it seems to be working.